# Recover Data Firestore Collection

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a service scheduling screen.

But there is a problem:

I need to check if the date and time the user is trying to schedule is available or reserved.

```
Structure DB:
Companies
-Company ID (Document)
--name
--phone
---Schedules (Collection)
------Event1
--------Hour: 08:30
--------Date: 01/01/2018
------Event2
--------Hour: 09:00
--------Date: 05/01/2018
------Event3
--------Hour: 10:30
--------Date: 01/002/2018
```

I access Scheduling data with this code:

```
String dateExample = "01/01/2018"
String hourExample = "08:30"

FirebaseFirestore mDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference mDBCompaniesSchedules = (CollectionReference) mDB.collection("Companies").document(mId_Company).collection("Schedules")
.get()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {


        for (Schedules document : documentSnapshots.toObjects(Schedules.class)) {

            String dtSchedules = document.getSchedules_date();
            String hourSchedules = document.getSchedules_hour();


            if ( dtSchedules.equals(dateExample) && hourSchedules.equals(hourExample) ){

                //Execute a "Toast" and closes the operation


            } else {

                //Call up the scheduling function.
                startScheduling();              
            }   

        }
    }
})
```

Process:

I need to run this code and go through all the documents in that collection. I need to check and analyze whether the date and time of the schedule already exists.

**If there is**: Show a Toast and block.

**If there is no**: Executing a specific function for the schedule record ("startScheduling()").

Problem:

When the data exists (it will only be once) then it will work.

**When there is no data, it falls into the ELSE loop. And it is executing several times the same function "startScheduling();".**

I need some way to go through this collection and when I do not find any results, the function "startScheduling (), be executed only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This how a `for loop` works. It will continue iterate till the last element to see if the condition is true or not. With other words, your `if-else statement` is triggered for every iteration in the loop. It means that, if the condition is `true` it will go with the `if part`, if the condition is `false` it will go with `else part`, for each and every element.

There are two ways in which you can solve this. One would be to `break` the loop once the condition was fulfilled. But this means that will iterate till it gets that element. Second, would be to change the logic of your code. Use first the if statement and second iterate.

**Edit:** The best option in this case would be to query your database using `whereEqualTo()` method.

```
Query query = db
    .collection("Companies")
    .document(mId_Company)
    .collection("Schedules")
    .whereEqualTo("dtSchedules", dateExample)
    .whereEqualTo("hourSchedules", hourExample);
```

In which `dateExample` and `hourExample` are the actual values with which you want to compare.

To count the number of documents in a Collection, please use the following code:

```
public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {
    if(documentSnapshots.size() == 0) {
        startScheduling();
    }
    for (Schedules document : documentSnapshots.toObjects(Schedules.class)) {
        String dtSchedules = document.getSchedules_date();
        String hourSchedules = document.getSchedules_hour(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you help me with that? @AlexMamo

Comment: I gave you 2 solutions. Which one can you not implement?

Comment: The way it is today. What is the best? @AlexMamo

Comment: To change the logic I do not know to tell you why I need to perform this query and see if the date and time are available. @AlexMamo

Comment: It would be like in my example question, but with clauses like WhereEqualTo ()? @AlexMamo

Comment: Yes, that correct. But remeber that in this case, the if-else statement is no needed anymore.

Comment: I understand. I think I've tried this. And I was not successful. The problem is when I can not find anything, where do I call it the Function (startScheduling(); )? @AlexMamo

Comment: Why it would be a problem? To solve this, you only need to select all from collection and count on the client side. Is the count is zero (could not find anything) then call `startScheduling()` method. That's it.

Comment: How could I do that? Please!! @AlexMamo